# Addind and removing UI elements in restartless TB addon

Tags: thunderbird-addon

I develop a restartless addon for Thunderbird. I need to add some UI elements in compose window when the addon is activated.

What I did so far is:

- at startup, add an observer on windows via nsIWindowWatcher
- at shutdown, remove window observer, and set a variable X to true
- when this observer observes domwindowopened event, add a eventlistener to the opened window for "compose-window-init" event (when it observes domwindowclosed, it removes the eventlistener)
- when this compose-window-init event is fired, check the document.location of the window, if it corresponds to a message composer:

  - add the UI elements,
  - or remove UI elements and remove eventListener, if X is set to true

This works well (UI is added to compose message when addon is activated, and removed when deactivated) except the following : when addon is deactivated then activated again, the first compose message is not provided with the UI elements. The UI is added to the other one, but not to the first.

Any idea on why and how to solve this ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong.

See my post at:
http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2949755&p=14254205#p14254205

Regards